# How to prove whether this grid puzzle is unsolvable/solvable?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, puzzle

[Disclaimer: I have researched a bit before this post and I have found no other questions that address my problem **specifically**, hence this post]

So I have been made a puzzle concept in a python program of mine, you have a 4 x 4 grid of lights, all of which are off at the start of the puzzle, your goal is to turn all the lights on.

The positions of the grid of lights is as follows:

```
1   2   3   4
5   6   7   8
9   10  11  12
13  14  15  16
```

The way you change the state of the lights is that you click the lights in the grid, each individual light affects a fixed set of lights in the grid unique to that individual light only. To clarify with an example: Imagine I click the first light in the grid, and it inverts the state of the lights at positions 1, 5, 8 and 10, and on clicking the light at position 2 of the grid it inverts the state of the lights at positions 2, 7, 9 in the grid.
(From now on, I will be calling this as "mapping", for example: the mapping of light 2 is to lights 2, 7, 9)

If you know of the game LightsOut, its like that except the lights inverted are spread across according to a formula I used, instead of being the neighbors of the light clicked.

(if you are confused still and need clarification, refer to the pictures I have linked at the end of this question, I hope that will resolve any queries, if any topic is unclear then I will edit this post to explain in a better way)

So now moving on to the question I have:

I have a certain mapping for the lights which is as follows:

```
Light 1  inverts lights 1, 5, 8, 11, 14

Light 2  inverts lights 7, 10, 13, 16

Light 3  inverts lights 2, 9, 12, 15

Light 4  inverts lights 1, 4, 5, 11, 14

Light 5  inverts lights 3, 7, 13, 16

Light 6  inverts lights 2 , 5, 9, 15

Light 7  inverts lights 1, 4, 7, 8, 11

Light 8  inverts lights 3, 6, 10, 13 

Light 9  inverts lights 5, 8, 12, 15

Light 10 inverts lights 1, ,7, 10, 11, 14

Light 11 inverts lights 3, 9, 13, 16 

Light 12 inverts lights 2, 5, 11, 15

Light 13 inverts lights 1, 4, 7, 13, 14

Light 14 inverts lights 3, 6, 9, 16

Light 15 inverts lights 2, 5, 8, 11

Light 16 inverts lights 1, 4, 7, 10, 13
```

Using this mapping I have been trying to solve from a state where all lights are off to where all lights are on for TENS of hours, I have made literally 83 algorithms to help in some cases, but I am unable to turn all of them on.

However when I made the 9th element 1 and the rest as 0, essentially modified the starting grid configuration, I was able to solve it using my algorithms.

SO FINALLY, my questions are:

**1) Is it possible to solve this grid with the given mapping?**

**2) I want to know a proper method I can use to prove whether the puzzle is solvable with a given mapping, a general method I can apply to any mapping**

**3) The way I generate a mapping is very simple, mainly addition of one number to a list of numbers,  and its definitely not the standard, if you are aware of a better way to reliably generate mappings, that is used in professional games/ professional settings, please let me know, I realize that this may be considered more of a puzzle/ CS question, but if you know a way, please let me know, however the main answers I want are for Question 1 and 2**

Here are the pictures for better understanding, *however I have changed the lights in the program to be represented by 1s and 0s for more compatibility in mathematical understanding, 0 indicates off, and 1 indicates on*:

[Initial Grid Set-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlwyH.png)

[The grid when the first light is clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmCh0.png) (inverts lights at position 1, 5, 8, 11, 14)

[The grid when the second light is clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byMho.png) (inverts lights at position 7, 10, 13, 16)

[End Goal configuration of grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRsmM.png)

Comment: Are you familiar with linear algebra? If so, work in $M_{16}(\mathbb{Z_2})$ and figure out if the all 1 vector is in the range space.

Comment: To clarify, he means using a 16 by 16 matrix of "bits", eg working in modulo 2.  Your constraints can all be described as linear equations modulo 2.

Comment: Lookup Gaussian elimination. Look at first light. Instead of having 1 and 4 in your base operations, you’d have 1 and 1+4 in your base operations. Adding 1 to 4,7,10,13,16 gives a new set of operations which are just as strong as the previous ones, but only 1 flips row 1.  Do the same to the rest until you get that only light 1 flips 1, only light 2 flips 2, etc. then, to flip 1 to 16 first flip 1, then see what the smallest thing you need to flip, flip that one, keep going using the only operation that would flip the smallest one.

Comment: @Eric I don't know about the Gaussian elimination, but I get the idea that you're getting at. That's actually what I used in my algorithms, I tried to generate as many as I could that would flip the least amount of lights, the the least I could flip was 2, and there were around 8 of them but I was never able to get a single light flipped ever, which makes sense seeing the mapping. I'll look into Gaussian elimination as well though since it can help me in other places, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, put your rules into a matrix:

[image]

Then, you can do something called "row reduction" modulo 2. This involves adding copies of some rows to other rows (where $1+1=0$) and possibly switching some rows around. A set of rules will be solvable from any initial state exactly when the row reduced matrix has a single 1 in each row and column. If we row reduce the above matrix we get:

[image]

We can see that there are states from which the game is not solvable. In fact, because there are three rows of zeroes, there are three conditions any game state that can reach the lights out position must satisfy.

You can get these equations by calculating the null space of the matrix, which is given by the three rows of this matrix:

[image]

If we let $L_i$ be $1$ if it is on and $0$ if it is off, then, unpacking the first row, we see that
$L_4+L_7+L_8+L_9+L_{11}+L_{15}+L_{16} \mod 2$ does not change under any of your above moves. This means that you can never go between the state of no lights turned on to the state of say, just $L_4$ turned on, or indeed any odd combination of $L_4,L_7,L_8,L_9,L_{11},L_{16}.$

In particular, to answer your question of whether you can go from the all lights on state to the all lights off state, since $L_4+L_7+L_8+L_9+L_{11}+L_{15}+L_{16}$ evaluates to $7=1\mod 2$ for all lights on, this is impossible.

The other two rows of the null space matrix give two other sums of lights that don't change (up to parity) under your moves.

Interestingly, if you look at the row reduced matrix, the $1$ in the upper left has only zeroes in its row. That means that you can toggle the first light in any game position using a combination of the legal moves.

Comment: If light number 1 changes the states of *all* of the lights, while all other lights do nothing, the initial matrix would have first row all 1's and all other rows 0. It would already be row-reduced. And one can go from no lights on directly to all lights on by throwing switch number 1. However this reduced matrix does not have a single 1 in every row and column.

Comment: ok so i have three queries after reading this question: 1) How did you get the row reduced form, did you perform elementary operations on the matrix? or did u get the row reduced echelon form? 

2) How did you 3rd matrix, the 16x3 one? 

3) when do we say the puzzle is solvable? When we have only 1 in each row in a diagonal? or if there is only 1 in each row in any position within the row?

Comment: @coffeemath right. Looks like the question I was answering was whether you could go from an arbitrary state to lights off, not just all lights on. Somehow, I missed that the OP was looking at a special starting state.

Comment: @coffeemath however, the calculation of the null space and the three linear expressions that are preserved by the OP's rules are still correct, in particular implying that the game is not solvable from an all lights on state, since the first functional evaluates to 1 on the all lights on state.

Comment: @ateeq 1) I performed elementary operations: adding rows to other rows and switching rows in order to get the reduced echelon form. Modulo 2 there are no other operations. 2) For this one, i actually used a computer algebra package, though it can be done by hand. Wolfram Alpha could probably handle it. 3) Yes it could be in any position, but after rearranging the rows, it would be a nice diagonal line. Note that as coffeemath alluded to above, this condition says that the game is solvable from any initial configuration of lights, which is a stronger condition than what you asked.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip Hmm okay, but regarding your last two lines, you're saying that the puzzle is solvable from any initial configuration of lights, but then in your answer you said that with the given light mapping, the puzzle is not solvable, so that's two contradicting statements. Am I misunderstanding something? If so can you clarify please

Comment: @ateeq sorry for being confusing. A good way to say it is that the puzzle is solvable from any initial state if the reduced matrix is a diagonal row of 1s. It is solvable from the all lights on state if the all lights on state evaluates to zero on all the rows of the null space. For your particular case, this doesn't happen, so it is not solvable from the all lights on state.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip Ah now I understand, alright. Thank you for all your help. So as a final confirmation, the method to find out if the puzzle is solvable with any given mapping is:

`1) Create a matrix corresponding to given mapping

2) Perform elementary operations on it to get reduced echelon form (Sidenote: can Gaussian elimination be used?)

3) If there is only a single 1 in each row of the matrix then it is solvable, else not`

Did I get that right?

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip with my setup for the moves, if the initial board has all lights on, one could flip any of the 15 switches which alter nothing, and end with all lights on. Of course from an initial board which has at least one light on and at least one light off, my moves will not solve that board.

Comment: @coffeemath I agree. Did I say something that contradicts that?

Comment: @Ateeq your understanding is right if "solvable" means "solvable from any starting position."

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip Yes that would be right, since its inclusive of all 0s state. But anyways , thank you for all the help on this problem of mine.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip I assume you have software which can row reduce over integers mod 2. If so, then it might be used to attack the question of whether or not all lights on can be reached from the specific starting board of all lights off. My idea is that you add a 17th column of all 1's to your 16x16 matrix, and then row reduce. If the state of all 1's cannot be reached, I think there would appear a row of 16 zeroes followed by a 1 in the augmented column. Would this constitute a test of whether or not one can go from all off to all on using the OP's moves? If so what happens?

Comment: @coffeemath I've already proven that the OP's moves aren't sufficient because they preserve a sum of a particular set of 7 lights (as well as two other conditions). That sum is $1$ for all on, and $0$ for all off, mod 2. For the general case, something like what you propose might work, I'd have to think about it a bit.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip Hey, sorry to contact you even though you've answered my question, but if possible could you tell me what I would have to do to the matrix in order to confirm if a mapping would work on a particular initial state, I want to implement that in my program and would really appreciate if you could tell me how.

Comment: @ateeq it's probably easiest to discuss with a smaller example, so I can illustrate all the steps. I will try to work on that later today.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip Yes that's completely fine, and easier for both of us. I'm Thankful for any sort of help